# tfs preview and software licenses

Tags: tfs, licenses.licx

Recently moved project to tfs preview and having trouble with software licenses installed on local dev boxes building correctly but on on tfs preview.

TFS fails the build saying it can't access registry due to those dll's that require installation. When removing the license contents from the .licx file tfs builds ok but the resulting drop and install issues a warning due to the license not being imbedded in the .exe.

Is there a way to install 3rd party licenses on tfs preview or is there another work around I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using the hosted build controller. If so, you can't install software on those machines as they use standard base images and are reset after each build.

Any builds where you want/need custom software installed are best done using your own build server, either with an on premise machine or an IAAS VM in Azure.

For reference the software included on the hosted build servers is [listed here](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/hosted-build-controller-in-vs#software).